# How to request USB permissions in Jetpack Compose with Accompanist?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I am migrating a Android app to Jetpack Compose. Following this connectivity [USB tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host#permission-d) I requested USB permissions on the usb device that I am trying to connect.

Now with Jetpack Compose I think accompanist is the recommended approach to handle permissions.

https://google.github.io/accompanist/permissions/

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
@Composable
private fun FeatureThatRequiresCameraPermission() {

    // Camera permission state
    val cameraPermissionState = rememberPermissionState(
        android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    )

    if (cameraPermissionState.status.isGranted) {
        Text("Camera permission Granted")
    } else {
        Column {
            val textToShow = if (cameraPermissionState.status.shouldShowRationale) {
                // If the user has denied the permission but the rationale can be shown,
                // then gently explain why the app requires this permission
                "The camera is important for this app. Please grant the permission."
            } else {
                // If it's the first time the user lands on this feature, or the user
                // doesn't want to be asked again for this permission, explain that the
                // permission is required
                "Camera permission required for this feature to be available. " +
                    "Please grant the permission"
            }
            Text(textToShow)
            Button(onClick = { cameraPermissionState.launchPermissionRequest() }) {
                Text("Request permission")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How should I request permissions for this use case?

```kotlin
val usbManager = getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE) as UsbManager
usbManager.requestPermission(device, permissionIntent)
```